# Is it possible to install IIS 7 on Windows XP?

Tags: iis, windows-xp, iis-7

Is it possible to install IIS 7 on Windows XP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You can't even install it on older server versions like Windows Server 2003.

Here is a list of all recent Windows operating systems with their corresponding IIS version:

- Windows Server 2000: IIS 5.0
- Windows XP Professional: IIS 5.1
- Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP Professional x64 Edition: IIS 6.0
- Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista: IIS 7.0
- Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7: IIS 7.5

Comment: You could install any one of the above within a Virtual Machine, with Windows XP as the host O/S - using Microsoft's Virtual PC or a VMWare solution.

Answer (score 2):

The free download [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=iisexpress) brings the IIS 7.x feature-set to Windows XP SP2+

[IIS Express will work with VS 2010 (SP1) and Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, will run on Windows XP and higher systems, does not require an administrator account, and does not require any code changes to use.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx)